# character attribute must be a single XML character error while unescaping some entities

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, saxon, saxparser, xslt-3.0

There are some user defined entites in the xml data. In order to unescape those entities, we are using entity reference in the DOCTYPE mentioned in the below code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
<!ENTITY sect "&amp;sect;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version='3.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' >
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" use-character-maps="mdash" />
<xsl:character-map name="mdash">
<xsl:output-character character="&#x2014;" string="&amp;mdash;"/>
<xsl:output-character character="&amp;" string="&amp;amp;" />
<xsl:output-character character="&quot;" string="&amp;quot;" />
<xsl:output-character character="&apos;" string="&amp;apos;" />
<xsl:output-character character="&sect;" string="&amp;sect;" />
</xsl:character-map>
<!--=================================================================-->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<!--=================================================================-->
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

while execution, we face the below error:-

```
  Error at xsl:output-character on line 11 column 64
  XTSE0020: character attribute must be a single XML character
```

This error is for sect entity on line 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the DTD, instead of `!ENTITY sect "&amp;sect;"` use `!ENTITY sect "&#167;"`.

Comment: There are some userdefined entities as well for which i dont see any character numeric value. How to define those entities?

Comment: @Rahul, ask that in a separate, new question, showing the necessary details. An entity replacement can of course consist of several characters in a DTD definition but the XSLT character map works on single characters only.